# chrome extension don't show any content but functional

Tags: mac, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

The extension suddenly become what the picture shows, you can use all of them,but it just render nothing to me
[pic http://cdn.dropmark.com/32736/1fdd96585f4058255f9562e3408f47facb6dc466/F27C3E26-2B87-4FCB-B36F-5ED3733E268F.png](http://cdn.dropmark.com/32736/1fdd96585f4058255f9562e3408f47facb6dc466/F27C3E26-2B87-4FCB-B36F-5ED3733E268F.png)
My chrome : Version 27.0.1430.0 dev
OS: OSX 10.8.2

Comment: Tried removing and reinstalling the extension?

Comment: yes,tried it before asking